# Windows 7 Ultimate WLAN problems

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, wireless-networking

I had to reinstall Windows on my machine after a HDD issue forced me to get a new one. Before, I had Windows 7 Enterprise installed and could connect to my WPA-PSK secured 802.11g router fine. Post reinstall, I have Windows 7 Ultimate and after it tries to gather information from the network it says Windows was unable to connect to the network. This is not the first time this issue has occurred (last time I could not connect I had Win7Pro I believe). Any suggestions?

Comment: Get the latest drivers from the manufacturer?

Comment: I can guarantee you that the problem is **not** caused by switching Windows 7 editions.

Comment: Sounds like either a driver problem or incorrect settings.  Have you tried connecting to other routers, or changing the passcode to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove and add the network. In some cases, the security protocol on old WLAN adapters is not supported and you need to check for new drivers.

Here is my short workaround:

1. Remove existing WLAN settings in Windows 7

   [image: WLAN]

   [image: LIST]

   [image: REMOVE]
2. Refresh WLAN list
3. Try to connect

In some cases, the password needs a special style to be supported from some drivers:

> http://www.andrewscompanies.com/tools/wep.asp

Comment: Hi Nasenbaer, I cannot try this now but will when I get home tonight.

Comment: was it helpfull?